# Is there an easy-to-use 0-1 IP solver for java?

Tags: java, smt, integer-programming, sat-solvers

I would like to use a 0-1 integer programming solver as a tool in a java program. I cannot find anything easy to use on the web. I tried the pseudo-boolean library from sat4j but this is not well documented, some classes are not consistent with their description in the API (some methods signature are different).

Would you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/), open-source package for LP and (mixed) ILP has [Java binding](http://glpk-java.sourceforge.net/).

Another open-source solvers are [lp_solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/index.htm) ([Java API](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/Java.htm)) and [SCIP](http://scip.zib.de/).

There are also commercial solvers - [CPLEX](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/optimization/cplex-optimizer/), [GUROBI](http://www.gurobi.com/products/gurobi-optimizer/gurobi-overview) and [Mosek](https://mosek.com/), all with Java interface.

Btw. for my homeworks, I found Python and [PuLP](http://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/) a bit easier to work with :)